# Recaptcha response null for valid answer

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to integrate Recaptcha with one of my forms. I somehow managed to put the recaptcha on the form and having it submitted using Curl (with help from this post : [What is blocking fsockopen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471942/what-is-blocking-fsockopen)). 
But the recaptcha doesn't seem to accept even the right answers.

I am no that good at PHP, but when debugged the code (offcourse using echo) found out that the the response is coming as empty. I have spent some 2 days on this, but still with no avail.

Do i need to make any changes in recaptcha_check_answer after including Curl?

Note: I am using WAMPServer 2.2 (Apache : 2.2.21, PHP : 5.3.10)

Here are the excerpts from my form code and submit code.

```
/**  Recaptcha display Code**/
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "6LeamtESAAAAAH-77WMLP5NqvCQR8g3ZMJ7kZJvV"; // you got this from recaptcha.org

$out = '<div><label for="captcha'.$form_id.'">* '.$field_object->field_label.'</label></div>';
$out .= recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
return $out;


/** Form Submit Code **/
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "6LeamtESAAAAAFM1d1Zd2XRDlTjxZRH8OaTowg7n";

$resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey,
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    if (empty($resp->error))
        $this->setFormError('captcha', __('You copied the number from the captcha field incorrectly.', 'custom-contact-forms'));
    else $this->setFormError('captcha', $resp->error);
}
```

Here is the modified recaptcha code

```
<?php

define("RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER", "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
define("RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");

function _recaptcha_qsencode ($data) {
        $req = "";
        foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
                $req .= $key . '=' . urlencode( stripslashes($value) ) . '&';

        // Cut the last '&'
        $req=substr($req,0,strlen($req)-1);
        return $req;
}

function _recaptcha_http_post($host, $path, $data, $port = 80) {

        $req = _recaptcha_qsencode ($data);
        $request = curl_init("http://".$host.$path);

        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "reCAPTCHA/PHP");
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $response = curl_exec($request);
        return $response;
}

function recaptcha_get_html ($pubkey, $error = null, $use_ssl = false)
{
    if ($pubkey == null || $pubkey == '') {
        die ("To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from <a href='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create'>https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create</a>");
    }

    if ($use_ssl) {
                $server = RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER;
        } else {
                $server = RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER;
        }

        $errorpart = "";
        if ($error) {
           $errorpart = "&amp;error=" . $error;
        }
        return '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. $server . '/challenge?k=' . $pubkey . $errorpart . '"></script>

    <noscript>
        <iframe src="'. $server . '/noscript?k=' . $pubkey . $errorpart . '" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
    </noscript>';
}

class ReCaptchaResponse {
        var $is_valid;
        var $error;
}

function recaptcha_check_answer ($privkey, $remoteip, $challenge, $response, $extra_params = array())
{
    if ($privkey == null || $privkey == '') {
        die ("To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from <a href='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create'>https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create</a>");
    }
    if ($remoteip == null || $remoteip == '') {
        die ("For security reasons, you must pass the remote ip to reCAPTCHA");
    }

        //discard spam submissions
        if ($challenge == null || strlen($challenge) == 0 || $response == null || strlen($response) == 0) {
                $recaptcha_response = new ReCaptchaResponse();
                $recaptcha_response->is_valid = false;
                $recaptcha_response->error = 'incorrect-captcha-sol';
                return $recaptcha_response;
        }

        $response = _recaptcha_http_post (RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER, "/verify",
                                          array (
                                                 'privatekey' => $privkey,
                                                 'remoteip' => $remoteip,
                                                 'challenge' => $challenge,
                                                 'response' => $response
                                                 ) + $extra_params
                                          );

        $answers = explode ("\n", $response [1]);
        $recaptcha_response = new ReCaptchaResponse();

        if (trim ($answers [0]) == 'true') {
                $recaptcha_response->is_valid = true;
        }
        else {
                $recaptcha_response->is_valid = false;
                $recaptcha_response->error = $answers [1];
        }
        return $recaptcha_response;
}

function recaptcha_get_signup_url ($domain = null, $appname = null) {
    return "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create?" .  _recaptcha_qsencode (array ('domains' => $domain, 'app' => $appname));
}

function _recaptcha_aes_pad($val) {
    $block_size = 16;
    $numpad = $block_size - (strlen ($val) % $block_size);
    return str_pad($val, strlen ($val) + $numpad, chr($numpad));
}

/* Mailhide related code */

function _recaptcha_aes_encrypt($val,$ky) {
    if (! function_exists ("mcrypt_encrypt")) {
        die ("To use reCAPTCHA Mailhide, you need to have the mcrypt php module installed.");
    }
    $mode=MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;   
    $enc=MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
    $val=_recaptcha_aes_pad($val);
    return mcrypt_encrypt($enc, $ky, $val, $mode, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
}


function _recaptcha_mailhide_urlbase64 ($x) {
    return strtr(base64_encode ($x), '+/', '-_');
}

/* gets the reCAPTCHA Mailhide url for a given email, public key and private key */
function recaptcha_mailhide_url($pubkey, $privkey, $email) {
    if ($pubkey == '' || $pubkey == null || $privkey == "" || $privkey == null) {
        die ("To use reCAPTCHA Mailhide, you have to sign up for a public and private key, " .
             "you can do so at <a href='http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/apikey'>http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/apikey</a>");
    }


    $ky = pack('H*', $privkey);
    $cryptmail = _recaptcha_aes_encrypt ($email, $ky);

    return "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k=" . $pubkey . "&c=" . _recaptcha_mailhide_urlbase64 ($cryptmail);
}

function _recaptcha_mailhide_email_parts ($email) {
    $arr = preg_split("/@/", $email );

    if (strlen ($arr[0]) <= 4) {
        $arr[0] = substr ($arr[0], 0, 1);
    } else if (strlen ($arr[0]) <= 6) {
        $arr[0] = substr ($arr[0], 0, 3);
    } else {
        $arr[0] = substr ($arr[0], 0, 4);
    }
    return $arr;
}

function recaptcha_mailhide_html($pubkey, $privkey, $email) {
    $emailparts = _recaptcha_mailhide_email_parts ($email);
    $url = recaptcha_mailhide_url ($pubkey, $privkey, $email);

    return htmlentities($emailparts[0]) . "<a href='" . htmlentities ($url) .
        "' onclick=\"window.open('" . htmlentities ($url) . "', '', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=500,height=300'); return false;\" title=\"Reveal this e-mail address\">...</a>@" . htmlentities ($emailparts [1]);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also experiencing these problems in all my sites, when running on development mode. Never mind if running with a virtual host (i.e.: mydomain.local) or just "plane" localhost (localhost/mydomain).  Once I switch to production on a real production server, recaptcha works like a charm.

So I guess it must be something related with Apache. The most sensible code would be the http request made througout php, but I've checked that fsockopen is working properly. No warning or error is shown, the mysterious thing is $response is always empty.

I've tried in my domain, [formacion online](http://formaciononline.eu), which is a VPS and it seems to work ok. Same settings in most values shown by phpinfo().

Comment: That was a useful info. Anyway, i have removed the recaptcha from my page validations and used a third party captcha. Will try with ur suggestion in the next web release.